# Tokenizing a Hashtag containing underscores with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, tokenize

We have been tokenizing twitter style hashtags with a word_delimiter filter. For a hashtag '#SomeHashtag' we expect users might search for `#SomeHashtag` or `SomeHashtag`.

For `#SomeHashtag` our analyzer produces the following tokens:
`#SomeHashtag`, `Some`, `SomeHashtag`, `Hashtag`

For `#Some_Hashtag`, which is common in some different languages, our analyzer removes the underscore from all tokens except the original:
`#Some_Hashtag`, `Some`, `SomeHashtag`, `Hashtag`

Here is our analyzer:

```
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "tweet_test": {
      "type": "custom",
      "char_filter": ["html_strip", "quotes"],
      "tokenizer": "standard_custom",
      "filter": [ "custom_text_word_delimiter_query"]
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "custom_text_word_delimiter_query": {
      "type": "word_delimiter",
      "generate_word_parts": "0",
      "generate_number_parts": "0",
      "catenate_words": "1",
      "catenate_numbers": "1",
      "catenate_all": "0",
      "split_on_case_change": "0",
      "split_on_numerics": "0",
      "preserve_original": "0",
      "type_table": [
          "# => ALPHA",
          "@ => ALPHA",
          "& => ALPHA",
          "- => ALPHA",
          ". => ALPHA",
          "/ => ALPHA",
          "_ => ALPHA"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

One solution we are considering is an additional pattern_capture filter such as:

```
"hashtag_filter": {
    "type" : "pattern_capture",
    "preserve_original" : 1,
    "patterns" : ["#([^\\s]*)"]
}
```

The actual regular expression twitter uses is MUCH longer than this (see https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/java/src/com/twitter/Regex.java).

Our application may index several hundred messages per second, so our questions are:

- Should we be concerned about the performance of a regular expression match?
- Is there an alternative approach that might be less expensive than a regular expression match?